# Why am I seeing artifacts from subview edges in images rendered from a UIView?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have a view (`viewA`) that is comprised of a grid of subviews. I am rendering `viewA`'s layer to an image context and seeing lines between the subviews. These lines are not there in screenshots, just when I render the view to an image context.

Here is a screenshot of `viewA`:
[image: Screenshot of <code>viewA</code>]

This is the image rendered from `viewA`:
[image: Image rendered from <code>viewA</code>]

I am using the following code to render `viewA` to an image context:

```
- (void)saveToPhotoAlbum:(id)sender
{
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIActivityViewController* avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:image] applicationActivities:nil];

    if ([[self class] iPad]) {
        if (popoverController) {
            [popoverController release], popoverController = nil;
        }
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:avc];
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:^{

        }];
    }
    [avc release];
}
```